# Task.Result waits instead of continue asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a Task that should run asynchronously but runs synchronously.

I've created a Task:

```
 var task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(proxy.BeginSaveImage(sp, new AsyncCallback(CompleteSave), state), proxy.EndSaveImage);

 int res =   task.Result;
```

The Task calls an asynchronous WCF service. The WCF Service function:

```
 public IAsyncResult BeginSaveImage(statePackage sp, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        gStatePackage = sp;

        // Create a task to do the work
        var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(this.SaveImage, state);

        return task.ContinueWith(res => callback(task));
    }
```

I run the task inside a loop.

My problem is that when I run it, it doesn't run in parallel and each call for `task.Results` waits for the task to be complete before continuing on.

When I put the Task code in a function `SaveImageProcedure` and call it from within the loop like that:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
 {
    SaveImageProcedure(sp);
 });
```

It runs asynchronously. I don't want to wrap an async call with another async wrapper. Why the call using `task.Result` doesn't run asynchronously and how can I change it to run async without wrapping it like I did to run async (or if it runs async, don't wait for results and continue the operation)?

I don't need the task returned value, and don't mind getting it but with the code continue to run for the next iteration in the loop without waiting for the result to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the `Result` field, you are waiting for the result to be available.
Try evaluating the result in a `Continue` or, use `await`

I'd expect something that looks like (pseudo code):

```
var task = Task<int>...
task.ContinueWith(result => {
    if (result != expected) throw new Exception("...");
});
```

Essentially, if you are doing one task and you have to get the result, you *will* be doing this part of the work flow synchronously. `Task` and `async` only allow you to do other things while you wait, they don't do any magic.

Comment: Hi Iain, how to use continue, can you provide an example please so I can try it in practice. Thanks

Comment: @IdanShechter the documentation tells you everything you need http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Google search query was `c# continuation`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [MSDN article on best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In particular, use `await` instead of `ContinueWith` or `Result`.

On the server side, there's no point in wrapping the work inside `StartNew`. It should just execute synchronously if it has only synchronous work to do.